# Detect if a windows machine has a virus scanner running?

Tags: .net, windows, virus-scanning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c)

In .net I would like to be able to detect of a windows box has a virus scanner running.

Windows 7 knows because in "Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center" it reports the status of your virus scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simmilar question was asked at [Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c)

Comment: accepted answer because it pointed me to the dulpicate question.
But I have marked my question for close.