# Missing directive or assembly reference using WMI ManagementObjectSearcher?

Tags: c#, windows, security, antivirus

I have found this link:

[Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c)

However when I try this code in visual c# express edition 2008 it says :

```
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ManagementObjectSearcher' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 15 17 ConsoleApplication1
```

Amongst other similar errors on the 2 lines which seem important!

Looks like the code segment is missing some imports or something?

I am using Windows 7... Please help!

Andy

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing a reference to the assembly containing the type `ManagementObjectSearcher`, which is in the `System.Management`namespace. Add this namespace and it should work.

You will have to rightclick the project -> add reference and add the System.Management assembly. System.Managment is not added automatically with the creation of a new project.

[WMI reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572(VS.85).aspx)
[WMI + C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340.aspx)

Comment: That is actually in the code see this pastebin to see exactly what I have :http://pastebin.com/y7s76Uf4

Comment: You have to add a reference to the project itself. see my edit.

Comment: Great it runs now - however it reckons i have no antivirus software installed, I am running Windows 7 - presume it is not supported. Do you know what would need to be changed in order to have it detect under windows 7?

Comment: Was able to sort it out actually by changing a line slightly : @"\root\SecurityCenter2" - do you know where the documentation is for WMI? and using it with c#?!

Comment: added two links in the post, but you should try and google yourself (just type `msdn searchphrase` and it will usually only find msdn entries, I searched for `msdn WMI` and `msdn WMI C#` respectively).

Comment: Thank you.I am struggling to find the information I need though - i am trying to get the property names for antivirusproduct but I cannot find them in the documentation?

Comment: I can't really help you with that, I would have to search myself. If you need further help, please ask another question.