# How to check programmatically if windows is up-to-date?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, wmi

I am building an application in c# using windows forms which has to detect if antivirus and antispyware are installed,updated and enabled.I have done this using WMI.Net,but I cannot find a way for checking if Windows 7 is up-to-date.
Do you know if this is possible through WMI or any other library ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. What does "up-to-date" mean here, that there are no pending updates to be applied?

Comment: yes,it means that there is no pending updates

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It is:

> a set of COM interfaces that enable system administrators and programmers to access Windows Update and Windows Server Update Services (WSUS). Scripts and programs can be written to examine which updates are currently available for a computer, and then you can install or uninstall updates.