# Turn on and off antivirus

Tags: c#

Is there a way to detect whether there is an antivirus software installed in a machine using C#? I know the Security Center detects antivirus software but how can you detect that in C#?And how to turn it off and on in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*How to detect it*: See the following question: [Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp)

*How to turn it off and on*: As far as I know, there is no simple, common way to turn off anti-virus software. And that's a good thing! Turning off anti-virus software should always be a conscious choice of the user (or the administrator in a corporate environment) and not be something that can be done easily by a third-party product.

Comment: Yeah... Imagine the malware you (accidentially) installed from the internet could do something like that...

Comment: @Heinzi thanks for the link . But it tells only that antivirus is installed or not ? Can we code in such a way that we can get the name of antivirus installed too.

Comment: @user1297661: Instead of just checking `instances.Count`, you can read the `displayName` property of the `AntiVirusProduct` record. See this page for a code example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37714/Software-Development-Build-your-own-Windows-Securi

Comment: Is it possible to decide wheter it is enabled. If I turn off for 10 minutes my antivirus software, the above link still says it is installed. I wan't to know if it is Enabled

Answer (score 0):

To return AntiVirus name as string:

```
 public static string Antivirus()
    {
        try
        {
            string firewallName = string.Empty;
            // starting with Windows Vista we must use the root\SecurityCenter2 namespace

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2", "Select * from AntivirusProduct"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mObject in searcher.Get())
                {
                    firewallName += mObject["displayName"].ToString() + "; ";
                }
            }
            firewallName = RemoveLastChars(firewallName);

            return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firewallName)) ? firewallName : "N/A";
        }

        catch
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
    public static string RemoveLastChars(string input, int amount = 2)
    {
        if (input.Length > amount)
            input = input.Remove(input.Length - amount);
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).