# Third Party Antivirus Name Fetch

Tags: c#

[Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp)

This link tells whether antivirus is installed in the system or not ? Can we code in such a way that we fetch the name of the antivirus installed too?

Comment: You have already ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920434/third-party-firewall-name-fetch. Please do not ask it again.

Comment: @Arion Hey that question was closed because i wrote the subject of my question in a wrong way by mistake.I have just rectified my mistake here.

Comment: @Arion i wrote firewall instead of antivirus there ( in the subject line ) . Still thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access wmi `displayName` property for each antivirus instance. Use [ManagementBaseObject.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties.aspx)

```
 string wmipathstr = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2";
 var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipathstr, "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
 var instances = searcher.Get();
 foreach (var instance in instances)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(instance.GetPropertyValue("displayName"));
 }
```