# Windows - How to trigger Anti Virus Updates via windows API / .NET / C# / WMI?

Tags: c#, wmi, antivirus

Is there a way to trigger Anti Virus updates process not by using The AntiVirus API ? whether  I know the Security Center detects antivirus software but how can you detect and update ?

There are a lot of posts on how to Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#/WMI, but Can I trigger an update process. Any ideas please?

[Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp)

Thanks In Advanced,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most programs allow you to use a command-line prompt to execute updates etc.

For Windows Defender, it comes with a command-line utility that lets you run updates, scans, etc. through the command-line. See [TN Run (and Automate) Windows Defender from the Command Line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg131918.aspx)

Windows Defender:

```
MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate
```

AVG (Anti-Spam & Program/Virus DB Updates):

```
avgmfapx.exe /AppMode=UPDANTISPAM 
avgmfapx.exe /AppMode=UPDATE
```

Once you know the Command-line Command, you can [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/1466627) to execute the update etc.

Comment: Thanks on the answer. Is there a knowledge base that gather such command lines?

Comment: @EldadCohen Not that I know, but [Google](http://www.google.com) is your friend. :)

Comment: @EldadCohen Don't forget to mark the question as answered, if it answered your question. :)