# How to get the latest patch updates of antivirus client in Windows 7 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, antivirus

Is there any way to know the antivirus patch updates in Windows 7 since WMI doesnt povide them.
I found that Windows Xp do provide the version Number but is there any other method to know the version number for Windows 7

```
Windows XP
Namespace : SecurityCenter
AntiVirusProduct-Properties

companyName
displayName
enableOnAccessUIMd5Hash
enableOnAccessUIParameters
instanceGuid
onAccessScanningEnabled
pathToEnableOnAccessUI
pathToUpdateUI
productUptoDate
updateUIMd5Hash
updateUIParameters
versionNumber

Windows Vista and Windows 7

Namespace : SecurityCenter2

displayName
instanceGuid
pathToSignedProductExe
pathToSigned
```

I need to develop an application that will provide me the patch updates of the antivirus in C#

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you could try:

```
string x = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
```

or another round about way is to run cmd.exe to run "ver"

```
string[] MyArguments = { "ver", ">text.txt"};
Process.Start("cmd.exe", String.Join(" ", MyArguments));
```

then open the file text.txt to parse the version information.

Comment: I dont need OS version.I need Antivirus 's version @SteveFerg

Comment: then check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp

Comment: Well even through `WMI` I wont get the version number in Windows 7 ...@SteveFerg

Comment: You can use the API from opswat called Metascan:  https://opswat.com/products/metascan though I do not know how much it costs, but they have a free demo.

Comment: there is also a powerShell you could try at: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-the-status-of-4b748f25

Comment: Just going through them...Thanks @SteveFerg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79932/discussion-between-techbrktru-and-steveferg).